# Eclipse, how to run multiple ant-targets

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build.xml

I have a bunch of java-projects, each project has a build.xml-file.

Now what I usually do is build project A and then deploy project A using a different build-xml file that's in another java-project.

Is there a nifty way of specifying what targets and what files I want to run, and in what particular order I want to run them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, you can add Builders to your project A that will kick off the build and then the deployment.  Go to the `Properties -> Builders` for the project and you can create `New...` ant builders that will invoke the targets using the ant build files that you specify.  Then in the `Builders` view you can specify the ordering to make sure the build is invoked before the deployment.

Comment: Good tip! But it didn't quite work for me, or a more probable theory - I'm not using it correctly! How do I start the chain of builders that I have?

Comment: The list of `Builders` are executed every time you build your project.  If your project isn't set to build automatically, then you'll have to select from the menu `Project -> Build Project`.